# Controlling the frequency of oscillation of SI530 VCXO

Tags: clock

I am thinking of using the [SI530 VCXO](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/si530.pdf) as a means to generate clock signal at frequency of 1.4 GHz.

But in the datasheet I do not pin which controls the frequency of oscillation. Can someone help!

Also I am thinking of using the output from this IC as clock input for EL16V IC for generating PECL compatible clock signal at 1.4 GHz.

Will it work?

Comment: On your buffer scheme, the part you are buying probably has something like an EL16 inside it (but not an actual EL16 because that requires 5 V, maybe an LVEP16). Adding an additional buffer stage probably just adds cost and jitter, so I wouldn't recommend it if you aren't gaining something from it (like if you were using a LVEP222 fanout buffer or something).

Comment: @ThePhoton so can I just use the si530 as a clock signal to my MC100EP016A counter ???            Or if is there a better option please suggest

Comment: Yes, you can directly connect the si530 (with 3.3 V PECL output option) directly to the EP016A, using standard PECL termination techniques (50 ohms to Vcc-2 or equivalent).

Comment: @ThePhoton but the si530 ic only has a LVPECL output option and not the PECL output ...

Comment: @ThePhoton ?????????????????????????

Comment: 3.3 V PECL  is one kind of LVPECL.

Answer (score 2):

What gave you the idea that Si530 is a VCXO? It says in the datasheet:

> The Si530/531 IC based XO is factory configurable for a wide variety
>   of user specifications including frequency, supply voltage, output
>   format, and temperature stability. Specific configurations are factory
>   programmed at time of shipment, thereby eliminating long lead times
>   associated with custom oscillators.

Maybe you should be looking at this page: http://www.silabs.com/VCXO

Comment: So if I was to order this ic off of digikey , what would the procedure be ???

Comment: @ironstein Dude, it's like ordering milk or bread.

Comment: So what about selecting the frequency of the crystal oscillator

Comment: Look at page 7 of the datasheet. Order the part number corresponding to the frequency you want.